# Getting error: "Column ambiguously defined "

Tags: sql

I am running the following query and getting column ambiguously defined :

```
SELECT 
    S.SUB_ID
    ,M.FLEETID
    ,M.TGID
    ,M.TGNO
    ,R.TGTYPE
    ,R.MODEID
    ,COUNT(1)
FROM 
    INF_SUBSCRIBER_ALL S
INNER JOIN 
    INF_TALKGROUP_MEMBER M ON S.SUB_ID = M.SUBID
INNER JOIN 
    INF_TALKGROUP_MODE_RELATION R ON M.TGID = R.TGID
INNER JOIN 
    INF_TALKGROUP_MODE_RELATION R ON M.FLEETID = R.FLEETID
WHERE 
    S.SUB_STATE = 'B01'
    AND M.STATUS = 'M01'
GROUP BY 
    S.SUB_ID, M.FLEETID, M.TGID, M.TGNO, R.TGTYPE, R.MODEID;
```

Comment: You are using `R` as a join alias twice - this should probably be fixed.

Comment: You should include the full message error.

Answer (score 0):

You have used aliase-`R` twice, that is why the error,

You dont need to include a table twice into JOINs for  adding another `condition`(`M.FLEETID = R.FLEETID`),

You can give the corresponding condition in the first occurce itselt using `AND` operator.

```
SELECT 
    S.SUB_ID
    ,M.FLEETID
    ,M.TGID
    ,M.TGNO
    ,R.TGTYPE
    ,R.MODEID
    ,COUNT(1)
FROM 
    INF_SUBSCRIBER_ALL S
INNER JOIN 
    INF_TALKGROUP_MEMBER M ON S.SUB_ID = M.SUBID
INNER JOIN 
    INF_TALKGROUP_MODE_RELATION R ON M.TGID = R.TGID AND M.FLEETID = R.FLEETID
WHERE 
    S.SUB_STATE = 'B01'
    AND M.STATUS = 'M01'
GROUP BY 
    S.SUB_ID, M.FLEETID, M.TGID, M.TGNO, R.TGTYPE, R.MODEID;
```

Hope this helps.